# Simulate a random walk

Tags: code-golf, random

## Context

In this challenge, a random walk is a stochastic process in which a particle at a position with integer coordinates (or a drunk man) moves at each integer time step (that is, at `t = 1, 2, 3, ...`) by taking a step of size `1` to any of its neighbouring positions, with the direction of the step being aligned with the axis, but chosen randomly

For example, in one dimension, we may have the following table of positions at the given times, starting at `t = 0` with the initial condition `p = 2`:

```
----------
| t |  p |
----------
| 0 |  2 |
----------
| 1 |  3 |
----------
| 2 |  2 |
----------
| 3 |  3 |
----------
| 4 |  2 |
----------
| 5 |  1 |
----------
| 6 |  0 |
----------
| 7 | -1 |
----------
| 8 |  0 |
----------
| 9 | -1 |
----------
   ...
```

## Task

Your task is to simulate a random walk in `n` dimensions from a supplied starting point, until the drunk man arrives at the origin **for the first time**, i.e. when we reach the point with coordinates `[0,0,...,0]` for the first time. *If we start at the origin, nothing has to be done because we already arrived.*

In the example above, the program would have stopped at `t = 6`.

You can take whatever probability distribution you want over the possible directions to go, so long as, for any position and any direction, there is a non-zero probability of that direction being picked.

Notice that your program must work for an arbitrary dimension, even though in practice, for higher dimensions it will not stop in a reasonable amount of time.

## Input

Any initial position with integer coordinates, of any positive size (so 1 or more). You can infer the dimensions of the random walk from the size of the input or you can take the dimension as an extra input. If you do, assume the dimension given matches the size of the initial position.

Input of initial position can be in any sensible format, including:

- a list of integers
- one input coordinate per function argument

Your program should work for any `n`, even though in practice it will time out for `n >= 3` unless you are incredibly lucky :)

## Output

You should return or print any of the following:

- all the intermediate positions occupied by the particle until the end of the random walk
- all the intermediate steps taken by the particle until the end of the random walk

The intermediate positions can be displayed in any human-readable way, as long as no two different positions are displayed the same way. Same applies to intermediate steps taken.

## Test cases

These should finish on TIO often:

```
[3]
[1, 0]
[0, -2]
[1, 1]
[-1,1]
[0]
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

These will probably timeout, but that is fine as long as your program runs:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 3, 0, -2, 100]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You can check [this reference program](https://tio.run/##jU/LioMwFN3nK860m2SaQmx3A36JiIiJNYzmSrSUfr29mnZWLgZCwrnncU/G59xRuC5LG2lArIPlxw8jxXlDPswaTUe@cRqTc1aI9ZYXJYR1LSY/3Pt6dlWyVo@6/5UjTepHAAE5ehc2zJCiv/l1Vhi0FFGBEftuTgZVClaMkfd95I/O9w4M8JW/vWso0BBFyzHvftJohHOmNs76yEwqLItzppGVieGgYnOWOOWrLk3/Ni67XykubE@iw/GAb1yNEvvKTBtt/q3m0vunVMsL) where I set the seed so that you can see it terminating for a random walk of 3 dimensions.

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest submission in bytes, wins! If you liked this challenge, consider upvoting it... And happy golfing!

Comment: Does that walk actually have to be random, or can we walk home deterministically?

Comment: And what exactly is the rule about stopping when you get to the origin? Can you keep going? Or pass it once but return and stop later? Does the stopping always have to happen in any run, or is this just part of the non-zero probability of arriving home?

Comment: @xnor I had used bad wording for that. I want non-zero probability of any direction being picked at any position, so we can't walk deterministically. You can use heuristics to weigh the chances, though. If you want that. And the stopping rule is the termination criteria for your program. Your program should stop as soon as you get home and only when you get home.

Comment: The point here really isn't about getting home. It is about simulating a random walk. "Getting home" is just some artificial criterion for your programs to be able to stop at some point and provide some observable output.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. To make sure, any distribution that gives nonzero chance to each direction at each point is valid then?

Comment: @xnor yes, that is correct. In other words, given any two points, there is a non-zero probability of going from one to the other. Correct?

Comment: For more than 2 dimensions there’s a nonzero probability that the walk never returns to the origin. So if the program outputs the steps when finished, it may never finish, and so no output will be produced. Is that allowed? Or should each step be output on the fly, producing a possibly infinite sequence of steps?

Comment: @LuisMendo It is ok that the program never finishes in those cases. You can output the steps on the fly or by the end of the program, that is up to you. I just want the programs to be able to handle arbitrary dimensions, I don't want to be maths :)

Comment: Are we allowed to print 0,0 or the origin?

Comment: @S.S.Anne yes that is fine

Comment: Because the probability of the directions doesn't have to be equal, I think a program that chose the dimension with the greatest absolute value with 90% probability, and chose to head toward the origin along that dimension with 90% probability, would comply and would reach the origin pretty quickly even for a high number of dimensions.

Comment: That's not a criticism, just an observation. Oh, and if two or more dimensions had equally high values it could pick between them with equal probability.

Comment: @DavidConrad that is correct, yes. But the point of the challenge is not to reach the origin, so I don't really mind if your program never really gets there :)

Comment: I realize reaching the origin isn't the goal, but was thinking about it because of your comment that a program will probably time out for high n "unless you are incredibly lucky :)"

Comment: Must we output the beginning and ending positions as well, or can one (or both) of them be omitted?

Comment: @JungHwanMin one or both may be ommitted

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13</s>  12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
LXṬ,N$X+µẸÐ¿
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of integers which yields a list of lists of integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//TFjhuawsTiRYK8K14bq4w5DCv////1sxLDBd)**

How?

```
LXṬ,N$X+µẸÐ¿ - Link: list of integers, p (length d)
          Ð¿ - collect up while...
         Ẹ   - ...condition: any? (when we reach [0]*d this does not hold
        µ    - ...do: the monadic chain - i.e. f(v); initially v=p:
L            -   length (of v) = d
 X           -   random integer (in range [1,d])
  Ṭ          -   untruth     e.g. 4 -> [0,0,0,1]
     $       -   last two links as a monad:
    N        -     negate              [0,0,0,-1]
   ,         -     pair                [[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,-1]]
      X      -   random choice         [0,0,0,1] OR [0,0,0,-1]
       +     -   add (to v)  e.g. [0,0,0,-1] + [4,2,3,2,5] = [4,2,3,1,5]
```

Comment: Nice Jelly submission! +1

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 99 bytes

```
#//.i_/;Union@i!={0}:>(i+RandomChoice@Select[Tuples[{-1,1,0},d=Tr[1^i]],#~Count~0==d-1&])&&Print@i&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczdCoIwGIDhWymEUTTTdZgsBt5AP3Y0VoztQz9wW9g8Er31JZ29J8/rdOzA6YhGp5anrCiO@C6qp8fgBW75VM7nyw4Pd@1tcHUX0IB4QA8mymb89PCVU84oo@VMLW8GyV6oFM2WOow@LiXnNmdE7Qm5DuijQJL@sRG3ESGKVk6rXf1pPaiUfg)

Comment: Nice submission! Thanks for your work +1

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>92</s> <s>87</s> <s>82</s> <s>81</s> 75 bytes

Input: the starting position (as list) and number of dimensions.

```python
def f(p,d):
 r=id(f)
 while any(p):p[r%d]+=r//d%2*2-1;print(p);r=hash((r,))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7LCoMwEEX3fsVFEJI24mun5EvEhRBDAhLDVCh@fZoodlPocBkOc2dx/LGbzXUhqEVDMy8U7zOQtIppnuFt7LpgdgfzvPcjFWp6SqoqVbSPtmwGT9btsRtImvllGCPBedAbwcM6sAxjN4m4G4H6hFqgbO9Tg5PKhFd7/0RAJCS8gm/1m1gl7eS/Li76RPVLLZf/JufhAw)

### Explanation

I created my own custom random generator as follow:

- `r=id(f)`: seed the generator - this is the source of randomness since the ID of `f` is different each time the program runs.
- `r=hash((r,))` generates the next random by hashing the tuple `(r,)`. This is the shortest I could find, as `hash(r)` just returns `r`, while `hash([r])` is not valid due to list not being hashable.

This ended up being shorter than using `random` or `time` module.

For each iteration, the program simply picks a random coordinate and add `1` or `-1` (randomly) to it.

- `r%d` is a random number between `0` and `d-1` inclusive, used to pick a random coordinate.
- `r//d%2` is a random number in \$\{0,1\}\$, and `(r//d%2)*2-1` maps it to \$\{-1,1\}\$.

`any(p)` checks if `p` has some non-zero coordinate, in which case the programs continue to run.

In case `id` and `hash` are not considered "random" enough, here is the same program but using `time` for randomness

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>92</s> <s>87</s> <s>82</s> 81 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @RGS*

```python
import time
t=time.time_ns
def f(p,d):
 while any(p):p[t()%d]+=t()%2*2-1;print(p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7NCoMwEITveYpBKCRtLP7cLD6JSCkYMaBx0UDx6dOsYi@FLsPOx84ehjY/zK4MwU40Lx7eTkb4mu3O6@lW0ZkevSTdqUrgPdjR4OU2Saqixkt16dpbzV5cizR/0GKdj2Ho5wUE6yAFmrLVceca2Q6ZRlqcpxw7pYxHev5EQCQwHsI3@lWMuCFXHY2LFZTA0Sap/02iwgc)

Comment: You can [save a byte](https://tio.run/##fY7NCoMwEITveYpBKCRtLP7cLD6JSCkYMaBx0UDx6dOsYi@FLsPOx84ehjY/zK4MwU40Lx7eTkb4mu3O6@lW0ZkevSTdqUrgPdjR4OU2Saqixkt16dpbzV5cizR/0GKdj2Ho5wUE6yAFmrLVceca2Q6ZRlqcpxw7pYxHev5EQCQwHsI3@lWMuCFXHY2LFZTA0Sap/02iwgc) if you do `import time; t=time.time_ns` instead of `from time import *; t=time_ns`.

Comment: Even though the id of `f` is different every time the program is run, it still remains the same in the same session, [for example](https://tio.run/##fYtBCoMwEADvecUiCLs1RdSbsi8JOQgxJFDSZSuor08LpdfOcZiRa0/PMtUatggRxQaaDSjngJEMnMDgvIEj5ccGa7lQaBanbfAda9@HdryN92E5O5ZFOa2vhKiWPqtoLjueVCO6yduBzNc0/I@GzK@vbw), which violates the rule of the function being reusable.

Comment: @JoKing Didn't know that, thanks! Still trying to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 48 bytes

```perl6
{{[(.rand+|0=>(-1,1).pick){^$_}Z+@$_]}...*.none}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/ujpaQ68oMS9Fu8bA1k5D11DHUFOvIDM5W7M6TiW@NkrbQSU@tlZPT09LLy8/L7X2f3FipUKaRrShjkGs5n8A)

Returns all intermediate positions.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                                              }  # Anonymous list
                                      ...  # Create sequence
 {                                   }  # Compute next item by
   (        =>           )  # Create pair with
    .rand+|0                # random integer in [0,dim) as key
              (-1,1).pick   # -1 or 1 as value
                          {^$_}  # Lookup values [0,dim)
                               Z+@$_   # Add to previous vector
  [                                 ]  # Store in array
                                         *.none  # Until all coords are zero
```

Comment: Cool perl submission! +1

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 161 bytes

```c
z(a,l,r)int*a;{for(r=0;l--;)r|=a[l];l=r;}p(a,l)int*a;{for(puts("");l--;)printf("%d,",*a++);}f(a,l)int*a;{for(srand(&l);p(a,l),z(a,l);)a[rand()%l]+=1-rand()%2*2;}
```

Prints all coordinates.

Example output:

```c
0,-2,
1,-2,
1,-1,
1,0,
2,0,
1,0,
0,0,
```

*-1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHdaoMwFIDvfYpg6cjRhCZ2tIPgkzgvgjZFyFKJ3S7m8uwuagdDHDPh3ITzfTk/qei1qobhE0uiiYXG3BMpenWz2OZMaEoF2K9cFroUOrfCtSP4G2vf7x2OY5jZ1vqUwvG@JjFJZJqCcGqpdFaaGj9pEPNrZKoOAmQxZWCvyzTn9HHJkky4wfvoTTYGf9yaGqI@2jUK8Qj5ozD22aKEHh2RI4iDQD@NvBpKqe9uCXKC2MhmG1hGEM22wv5hvpWlITDbOhoLG@0Ro/EcZJCF/bJm7y66u0SHw8r6/6n7h3Mk83/4XbBJPgXIATFt@7w@kqkbFbnhGw)

Comment: Nice submission! +1 This output is acceptable, don't worry. But why does it have all the leading `#`?

Comment: @RGS It was originally because without it you wouldn't be able to tell the coordinates apart. But now I might be able to remove it and the output would still be clear.

Comment: It may at least save one byte if you remove it from the code, no? and technically the output doesn't need to be pretty. It just needs to be "parseable"

Comment: @RGS There. That's much better. (before, all the coordinates were smashed together and you couldn't tell one set from the next)

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
Ｗ⌈↔θ«≔‽Ｌθι§≔θι⁺§θι⊖⊗‽²⟦Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY09C8IwGIRn/RUZ30A71NWp2EWwUFxDhzR5aQP5oPnQgvjbYwoK3nLw3HEnFu6F4zrn56I0Euj5pkwy0E7B6RQRVkopeR0PbQhqtnDnVjoDN7RzXPawIoqef3Ebr1biBmuhFRl0CvCPSrlD4dGgjSihc2nSxb@bJ7qrbA1e2QjswkMsD2NB75wZq5uKNOOY64f@AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⌈↔θ«
```

Repeat until the origin is reached. (`Ｗ⊙θκ«` also works for the same byte count.)

```
≔‽Ｌθι
```

Pick a random dimension.

```
§≔θι⁺§θι⊖⊗‽²
```

Move one step randomly along that dimension.

```
⟦Ｉθ
```

Output the new coordinates. The `⟦` double-spaces the coordinates for clarity, but if that's not required then it could be removed.

Bonus program:

```
ＪＮＮＷ∨ⅈⅉ✳⊗‽φ¹@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@rNLcgJF/DM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDU0cBhatpzVWekZmTqqDhX6QRAZKOBApqKgQUZeaVaLhkFqUml2Tm52m45Jcm5aSmaAQl5qXk52qkAdXoKBgCdUMUKjkoaVr//2/IpWv4X7csBwA) Takes two dimensions only. Sample output:

```
    |  
 ||----
----@  
||     
|-
```

Comment: I like the bonus program. +1 Is it printing some representation of the random walk?

Comment: @RGS It prints a `-` if it walks horizontally or a `|` if it walks vertically, but of course it also overwrites as it goes so it's nowhere near an acceptable representation for the purposes of the answer, but I thought it was cool to show what you could do in 13 bytes.

Comment: that is what I guessed. It is quite cool indeed! Thanks for sharing this :D

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[=D_P#āDΩQD(‚Ω+
```

Inspired by [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199921/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2tYlPkD5SKPLuZWBLhqPGmadW6kNFNU11DGMBQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
[           # Start an infinite loop:
 =          #  Print the current list with trailing newline (without popping),
            #  (which will use the implicit input-list in the very first iteration)
  D         #  Duplicate the current list
   _        #  Check for each value whether it is 0
            #   i.e. [0,4,0] → [1,0,1]
    P       #  And if all are truthy:
     #      #   Stop the infinite loop
  ā         #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
            #   i.e. [0,4,0] → [1,2,3]
   D        #  Duplicate it
    Ω       #  Pop and push a random value from this list
            #   i.e. [1,2,3] → 3
     Q      #  Check for equality; the random 1-based position becomes 1, the others 0
            #   i.e. [1,2,3] and 3 → [0,0,1]
      D(‚   #  Pair it with a negative copy of itself
            #   i.e. [0,0,1] → [[0,0,1],[0,0,-1]]
         Ω  #  Pop and push either of these two lists
            #   i.e. [[0,0,1],[0,0,-1]] → [0,0,-1]
          + # And the values at the same indices
            #  i.e. [0,4,0] + [0,0,-1] → [0,4,-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your 05AB1E solution! I was starting to think this would never happen :'(

Comment: ah I see. I thought you could code this in 5 minutes, like in the toilet :p have a nice week

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>68</s> <s>63</s> <s>61</s> 57 bytes

<sup>-4 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
param($n,$d)for(;$n-ne0){$n[(random $d)]+=1,-1|random;$n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT0clRTMtv0jDWiVPNy/VQLNaJS9aoygxLyU/VwEoFatta6ija1gDEQEqqv1fy8WlppKmoKFjrKlgyKWuDuEZ6hhoKhjBuQY6UKipYPofAA)

[Less Ugly Form for 2 extra bytes.](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT0clRTMtv0jDWiVPNy/VQLNaJS9aoygxLyU/VwEoFatta6ija1gDEbFWUslTqv1fy8WlppKmoKFjrKlgyKWuDuEZ6hhoKhjBuQY6UKipYPofAA)

The neat part of this answer is the for conditional, `$n-ne0`. When you apply comparison operations to arrays, it applies it to each element and acts as a filter, in this case filtering out all 0s. If we filter everything out (i.e., we're at `(0,0,...,0)`), we get an empty array and those are considered false. As a side note, for the singleton case, you have to explicitly cast the parameter to a list. Otherwise, it wants to play ball as an int which doesn't go over well.

I reread the comments and noticed you didn't need to print the initial config, saving 5 bytes. This now means things that start at the origin return nothing but that seems up to spec.

Comment: Hey there, I don't know what you mean by `n lines in a row represents a step` but it probably counts! :P

Comment: @RGS [Looks a bit like this](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT0clRTMtv0jDWiWvxr5aUVElvlazWiUvWqMoMS8lP1cBKB2rbWuoo2tYAxEBKqz9X8vFpaaSpqBhoGOoqWDEpa4O40KhpoLpfwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: That is fine, yes. It is annoying, but it is unambiguous.

Comment: may be `$n-ne0` instead `$n|?{!!$_}`?

Comment: @mazzy But that doesn't look as cool. (Thanks :D)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 46 bytes

`p(l)` prints the contents of `l` and then returns the same array as well, making things very convenient as we can wrap the print statement into the termination condition.

```ruby
->l,d{l[rand d]+=rand(2)*2-1until[]==p(l)-[0]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBDsIgEADAu6/gCBaocsePbDemhtZsslYC24O2fTvGOU1ZH582x@ZubNPGUMYlqYRd/EcHcw7uui5CDBhj1mwcXPBorKJ6TlJ9zUyie7BDxa43/jXmbaedfJVC2cv7TsdpBraKfaXvhC3Y8AM)

Comment: Looking good! :D +1

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>105</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>89</s></sup> 86 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Surculose Sputum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92237/surculose-sputum)!!!

```python
from random import*
def f(p,l):
 while any(p):p[randrange(l)]+=choice((-1,1));print(p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9NCoMwEIX3nmJ2ZmwCRneWnkRciCY1EJMQAsXTpxPFbgrz8zHvLd6EI23e9Tnr6HeIs1tpmT34mJpqVRo0C9ziUMFnM1bB7A4WcAhjsVK/FbM4PV7L5s2iGBOSS8RniMYlMmbtIyQwDlgFYz9xmpJDe0LLQXT3ScJJouCl3h4CIIKCV8FP@i@SStorQMKKHkjcKkeM97kWddP1mL8)

Comment: Good job on this sub +1!

Comment: Easy [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY9NCoMwEIX3nmJ2ZmwCRneWnkRciElqQJMQAsXTpxPFbgrz8zHvLd6EI63e9Tmb6HeIs1O07B58TE2ltAHDAlc4VPBZ7aZhdgcLOISxWKnfmimcHq9l9XbRjAnJJeIzROsSGbPxERJYB6yCsZ84TcmhPaHlILr7JOEkUfBSbw8BEEHBq@An/RdJJe0VIGFFDyS@aUeM97kWddP1mL8) if you take the number of dimensions as an extra input, which is allowed!

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Missed that - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## BATCH, <s>563 560 539 509</s> 653 bytes

```
@ECHO OFF 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "#=Set "
!#!/P N=D
!#!"F=For /L "
!#!I= in (1,1,
!#!D=) Do (
!#!E=) ELSE (
!#!C=CALL :
!#!Y=2
%F%%%A%I%!N!%D%
!#!O%%A=0
!#!/P S%%A=Ax%%A
!#!H%%A=!S%%A!)
%F%%%A%I%50000%D%
!#!v=0
!C!R U N
!C!M S!U! H!U!
!#!]=@
%F%%%B%I%!N!%D%
!#!"]=!]!!S%%B!,"
IF %%B==!N! !#!]=!]:~,-1!
IF !O%%B!==!S%%B! !#!/A v+=1
IF !v!==!N! GOTO :E
)
ECHO(!]!
)
:E
ECHO(!]!
pause
:M
!C!R R Y
!C!R P Y
IF !R!==1 (IF !%1! LEQ 0 (IF !P!==1 (!#!/A %1+=1%E%!#!/A %1-=1)%E%!#!/A %1-=1)%E%IF !%1! GEQ !%2! (IF !P!==2 (!#!/A %1-=1%E%!#!/A %1+=1)%E%!#!/A %1+=1))
Exit /B
:R
!#!/A %1=!random! %%!%2! +1
Exit /B
```

**Update**
At the cost of alot of bytes, I corrected the issues with zero chance for movement along any axis under the previous conditions, and through the use of an additional random test in an Ugly, byte hungry conditional statement still biased movement (In a non zero manner compliant with the terms outlined).
also modified the output to match the specified form.

[Example Output](https://pastebin.com/A2Zp3i3M)

Comment: numerical input for number of dimensions and each dimensions target position required. starting postion for each axis is set randomly to a maximum of target pos + 1 (reduces time to proccess). each step along each axis is randomly taken - or + 1, Steps along any axis cease to be taken after reaching the correct position for that axis

Comment: Constraint added to keep walker within the grid

Comment: this does not meet the requirements! At any position, it should be possible to go in any direction! If you stop walking in a direction when it reaches 0, this isn't true

Comment: post ammended to match the terms (I do hope I've got the non-zero terms right this time)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>63</s>  62 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>a.join``==0?[a]:[a,...f(a.map(x=>x+~-(3*Math.random())))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbR1i5RLys/My8hwdbWwD46MdYqOlFHT08vTSNRLzexQKPC1q5Cu05Xw1jLN7EkQ68oMS8lP1dDEwhi/yfn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpRBvHampyoYkZ6igYYBE20FHQNcKu3BCLsK6hDjZhHCbjEoYgvJLICKjwPwA)

Comment: Thanks for your submission! +1

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>83</s> <s>79</s> 75 bytes

```
For[r=RandomInteger;i=#,!0==##&@@i,j=r@{1,Tr[1^i]};i[[j]]+=2r[]-1,Print@i]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCsIwDADQu38xCmNihNVrCeQkeBvDW4hQtNMM2kHobezb63s51l/Kseo7tgWHdt@MDedYPlt@lJq@yYKig25EdK4nUljRaPfwNPYvlSMo8ypywZuxXD1MpqWSSt/O4bTQPoI/2h8)

Omits the last result (which is the origin anyway).

Comment: Nice solution! +1 for your work

Comment: @J42161217 That doesn't work because of some finnicky evaluations inside `Part` (observe that there are duplicate lines in the output sometimes) Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107621/35945

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 74 bytes

```matlab
x=input('');do disp(x),x(randi(size(x)))+=2*randi([0 1])-1;until~x;disp(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/wjYzr6C0RENdXdM6JV8hJbO4QKNCU6dCoygxLyVTozizKhXI19TUtjXSgghFGygYxmrqGlqX5pVk5tRVWEP1/P8PlgEA)

Comment: Thanks for your work! +1 for this